# The highest even number in a list

Tags: python

I want to find the highest even number in a list. The code I have used is able to do so successfully, but I don't know why my code is running right.

Please find my code below:

```
def highest_even(*list):
  for numbers in list:
    if numbers % 2 == 0:
      c= numbers
  print(c)

highest_even(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,111,222,444,555)
```

Even though I have only validated the even numbers, the output I am having is only the highest even number. Why is it so? Please help

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking why it _works_? BTW, if the inputs are not ordered, your function will not work. Try with `222` as a last element.

Comment: Adding my voice to Chris, what do you want?... Your question saying that you want the highest even element in the list. But at the end of your question you complicated it. Do you want the highest value in the list or sorting the list depending on the highest value?

Answer (score 2):

Your list is ordered and you replace the value of c by the last value you evaluated as even. So at the end you get the highest number, try to shuffle your list using `shuffle()` and you will not get the right result.

Here's how you can fix your function :

```
def highest_even(*list):
  c = 0
  for numbers in list:
    if numbers % 2 == 0:
      if numbers > c:
          c= numbers
  print(c)

highest_even(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,111,222,444,555)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a list of evens, sort it, and take first value from the right:

```
    def maxeven(list):
        return sorted([x for x in list if x % 2 == 0])[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this instead: -

```
def highest_even(list):
    evens = []
    for i in list:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(i)
    return max(evens) 

print(highest_even([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,111,222,444,555]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `print(c)` inside the `for()` loop like so:

```
for numbers in list:
  if numbers % 2 == 0:
    c = numbers
  print(c)
```

You get only the highest even number, because after the loop is done, you `print` only the last element.

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain the **Highest Even value** From your mentioned **tuple** not list by using **filter()** and **lambda Expression**.

#### Highest Even Element in The Tuple

**Code Syntax**

```
def highest_even(*tuple):
    lis = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, tuple)
    return print(f"your maximum even number is: {max(lis)}")

highest_even(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,111,222,444,555)
```

**Output**

```
your maximum even number is: 444

[Program finished]
```

---

#### Sorting Depending on Highest Even Element

**Code Syntax**

```
def highest_even_list(*tuple):
    lis = sorted(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, tuple), reverse=True)
    return print(f"Sorted List depending on The highest Even Elements:\n{lis}")
    
highest_even_list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,111,222,444,555)
```

**Output**

```
Sorted List depending on The highest Even Elements:
[444, 222, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

[Program finished]
```

---

#### Using Kwargs for Reversing

You can also decide if you want to sort it ascending or descending using ****kwargs**

**Code Syntax**

```
def highest_even_list(*tuple, **kwargs):
    lis = sorted(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, tuple), **kwargs)
    return print(f"Sorted List depending on The highest Even Elements:\n{lis}")
    
highest_even_list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,111,222,444,555, reverse=True)
```

**Output**

```
Sorted List depending on The highest Even Elements:
[444, 222, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

[Program finished]
```